# 2 Forms, Search in first and show values in 2nd Form

Tags: php, html

HTML Page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKYQU.png

Database Row with id = 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKYQU.png#1

When i click in submit button of 1st form I want to show the values of id = 1 in textboxes of 2nd form.

For example like this: http : // imgur.com / P95CyMv , VV4QYKS , xOE8RVA#2 (without spaces)

I do this and some hours before its working but i do something and its not working now.

HTML/PHP:

```
<form method="post">
                <p>Mostrar evento por:</p>
                <p>
                    <select name="select" id="select">
                        <option selected="selected">id</option>
                        <option>Nome do Evento</option>
                        <option>Data do Evento</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="nomeEvento" id="text" width="300">
                </p>
                <?php
                require ('sql_connect.php');

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $selectedItem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['select']);
                    $nomeEvent = mysql_escape_string($_POST['nomeEvento']);

                    if (!$_POST['select'] | !$_POST['nomeEvento'])
                    {
                        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                            window.alert('Tem de meter um username e uma password')
                            window.location.href='UpdateEvents.php'
                            </SCRIPT>");
                        exit();
                    }

                    $query = "select * from `eventos` where `$selectedItem` = '$nomeEvent'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $coiso1 = $row['nome'];
                        $coiso2 = $row['data'];
                        $coiso3 = $row['descricao'];
                        $coiso4 = $row['url'];
                    }

                    echo $selectedItem, $nomeEvent, $coiso1, $coiso2, $coiso3;

                }                   
                ?>                
                <p>
                    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Mostrar" onClick="NomeEvento('<?php echo $coiso1 ?>','<?php echo $coiso2 ?>', '<?php echo $coiso3 ?>');">
                </p>
            </form>

            <form method="get">
              <p>Nome do Evento:</p>
              <p>
                <input name="text1" type="text" id="text1" width="300">
              </p>
              <p>Data do Evento:</p>
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="text" id="text2" width="300">
              </p>
              <p>Descrição:</p>
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="text2" id="text3" width="300">
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Alterar">
              </p>
            </form></p>>
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:

```
<script>
        function NomeEvento(nomeEvento, dataEvento, descricaoEvento)
        {    
            document.getElementById("text1").value= nomeEvento;
            document.getElementById("text2").value= dataEvento;
            document.getElementById("text3").value= descricaoEvento;
        }

        </script>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: If it was working before, then you should probably identify what you changed. Also, be more descriptive than "its not working". In what way is it not working? What _is_ happening?

Comment: I dont know what i changed, Before its showing the values in second form. Now its not showing...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `$coiso1`, `$coiso2`, and `$coiso3` before they have been defined. They are only defined when processing the form submit, but you are attempting to use them on initial page load as part of the button click handler.

Comment: I would recommend doing the submit/post via ajax and then use the results to populate the desired fields. There are many guides/tutorials out there, as well as questions here regarding how to do that. Just do some research. Conversely, try to figure out what you changed. I'm really not sure why you don't at least have a general idea of what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

At moment, when you click on submit button you are not have `$coiso1`, `$coiso2` and `$coiso3` variables, because your php script will populate it only on POST request.

Try to call method `NomeEvento(var1, var2, var3)` at page load.

Comment: `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` don't exist either so that's not going to help any.

Comment: Replace `var#` with real variable.